# ruby-on-rails: mocking a route in functional test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-test

I have a route in my routes.rb file:

```
map.connect 'login', :controller => 'users', :action => 'login'
```

and I have a partial being rendered in a view as:

```
login_path
```

This view gets called in the functional test of the controller.

However, in the functional test I get the error:

```
ActionView::TemplateError: undefined local variable or method `login_path' for #<ActionView::Base:0x4762c90>
```

1) What's the best way of mocking it for the test?

2) Does this indicate a design flaw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`map.connect` will add an unnamed route. What you probably want in your `routes.rb` is:

```
map.login 'login', :controller => 'users', :action => 'login'
```

That will create the named routes `login_path` and `login_url` for you.